# How to edit "view on site" url on django admin?

Tags: python, django

How in the modern version of Django edit the "view on site" url on django admin?

Answer (score 0):

in your model implement `get_absolute_url` method like this

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse('model_record_view',args=[self.id])
```

where model_record_view is the name of the view and it is id as a paramter

Comment: Did you mean reverse the named url, not the view? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns